# How to get the shell image index of an object in the shell namespace?

Tags: shell, delphi

I want to get the index in the system imagelist of an object in the shell namespace.

If this object was a **file** i could use [`SHGetFileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179.aspx):

```
function GetFileImageIndex(const Filename: string): Integer;
var
   sfi: TSHFileInfo;
begin
   SHGetFileInfo(PChar(Filename), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, sfi, SizeOf(sfi), 
         SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES or SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX);
   Result := sfi.iIcon;
end;
```

Except i don't have a file

The thing i have doesn't exist on the hard-drive as a folder or file, e.g.:

- `Control Panel`
- `Homegroup`
- `Network`

But i still need to get the index in the system imagelist of the icon that corresponds to this thing. I started with `SHGetFileInfo` (as it supports pidls). But that fell apart. Then i tried using `IExtractIcon`, but that fell apart:

```
function GetObjectImageIndex(ParentFolder: IShellFolder; const ChildPidl: PItemIDList): Integer;
//var
//  sfi: TSHFileInfo;

//  extractIcon: IExtractIcon;
//  iconFile: WideString;
//  iconIndexInFile: Integer;
//  flags: Cardinal;
begin
    {
        This function is the shell namespace equivalent of GetFileImageIndex helper function.
    }
(*
    Won't work (MSDN: "The PIDL must be a fully qualified PIDL. Relative PIDLs are not allowed.")
    SHGetFileInfo(PWideChar(ChildPidl), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            sfi, SizeOf(sfi),
            SHGFI_PIDL or SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX);
*)

(*
    Won't work. Doesn't return an index into the system imagelist
    ParentFolder.GetUIObjectOf(0, 1, ChildPidl, IExtractIcon, nil, {out}extractIcon);
    SetLength(iconFile, MAX_PATH);
    extractIcon.GetIconLocation(0, PWideChar(iconFile), Length(iconFile), iconIndexInFile, {out}flags);
*)

    Result := -1; //TODO: Figure out how to do it.
end;
```

Given an `IShellFolder` and a `pidl` in that folder, how do i get the icon in the system imagelist of that thing?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you pass an absolute PIDL that identifies the object to `SHGetFileInfo`. You say you tried that without success, but this is the way to solve your problem.

You should go back to `SHGetFileInfo` and make it work. It looks like you got as far as having a relative PIDL and stopped. Make an absolute PIDL with `ILCombine` and you should be home.

If you don't have a PIDL for the containing `IShellFolder` then you'll want to read this topic: [How to obtain the PIDL of an IShellFolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766275/how-to-obtain-the-pidl-of-an-ishellfolder)

Answer (score 0):

```
function CreateGlobalChildIDList(AParentFolder: IShellFolder; const AChildIDList: PItemIDList): PItemIDList; forward;

function GetObjectImageIndex(AParentFolder: IShellFolder; const AChildIDList: PItemIDList): Integer;
var
  ShellIcon: IShellIcon;
  ChildIDList: PItemIDList;
  FileInfo: TSHFileInfo;
begin
  try
    Result := -1;
    try
      OleCheck(AParentFolder.QueryInterface(IShellIcon, ShellIcon));
      try
        OleCheck(ShellIcon.GetIconOf(AChildIDList, GIL_FORSHELL, Result));
      finally
        ShellIcon := nil;
      end;
    except
      Result := -1;
    end;

    if Result = -1 then
      begin
        ChildIDList := CreateGlobalChildIDList(AParentFolder, AChildIDList);
        try
          ZeroMemory(@FileInfo, SizeOf(FileInfo));
          SHGetFileInfo(PWideChar(ChildIDList), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FileInfo, SizeOf(FileInfo), SHGFI_PIDL or SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX);
          Result := FileInfo.iIcon;
        finally
          CoTaskMemFree(ChildIDList);
        end;
      end;
  except
    Result := -1;
  end;
end;

  function CretaeGlobalChildIDList(AParentFolder: IShellFolder; const AChildIDList: PItemIDList): PItemIDList;
  var
    PersistFolder2: IPersistFolder2;
    PersistIDList: IPersistIDList;
    ParentIDList: PItemIDList;
  begin
    if Succeeded(AParentFolder.QueryInterface(IPersistFolder2, PersistFolder2)) then
      try
        OleCheck(PersistFolder2.GetCurFolder(ParentIDList));
        try
          Result := ILCombine(ParentIDList, AChildIDList);
        finally
          CoTaskMemFree(ParentIDList);
        end;
      finally
        PersistFolder2 := nil;
      end
    else
      if Succeeded(AParentFolder.QueryInterface(IPersistIDList, PersistIDList)) then
        try
          OleCheck(PersistIDList.GetIDList(ParentIDList));
          try
            Result := ILCombine(ParentIDList, AChildIDList);
          finally
            CoTaskMemFree(ParentIDList);
          end;
        finally
          PersistIDList := nil;
        end
      else
        raise Exception.Create('Cannot create PIDL');
  end;
```